# Why the Pillarbox effect used in this scene?

Tags: effects, the-wolf-of-wall-street

In the scene of *The Wolf of Wall Street (2013)*, where Real Jordan Belfort welcomes reel
actor Jordan Belfort onto the stage. Pillarbox effect is
used.

[image]

It comes to normal aspect ratio when he asks people sell him a pen. Why the Pillarbox effect used in this scene?

Comment: IMDB https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0993846/technical says some scenes were shot in the 1.85:1 aspect ratio. This is why that scene has to have pillar-boxing. I don't know why they did it though. It would be very interesting to find out if someone knows.

Comment: What is reel actor?